# Does the REElocate plugin bij exp:resso actually moves my ExpressiongEngine website or does it copy it?

Tags: plugin, expresso

Does the REElocate plugin bij exp:resso actually moves my ExpressiongEngine website or does it copy it?  I have an ExpressionEngine website and I'd like to copy this to another domain (thus server), for an development/experiment environment. So whenever I use the REElocate plugin, I hope it doesn't actually move my whole website. :P  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think it does either.  I’m pretty sure all it does is fix up the various config strings within an EE database to point to the correct locations after the MySQL has been moved over to a new machine.  The moving of the rest of the assets that make up your website is down to you to do.